# Get current user details from Grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana

Can anybody help me to get current logged in user's details(at-least email) from Grafana dashboard.
I am creating custom panel plugin in Grafana and required the user details. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, this may help someone else.
You just need to import config from app/core and you will get user details under

> config.bootData.user

like this:

```js
import config from '../../../../public/app/core/config';
interface Props extends PanelProps<SimpleOptions> {}
console.log(config.bootData.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the grafana runtime lib.

```js
import { config } from '@grafana/runtime';

console.log(config.bootData.user);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call Grafana API `GET /api/user` - [API doc](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/user/#actual-user).

Comment: Getting response 404 "User not found", while user of that organization is already logged in.